# why does request format change after data mapper mediator

Tags: wso2

now I have came across a problem I can't resolve while using WSO2 EI.
The problem is I want to transform some data before the message reaching the endpoint by using data mapper mediator.
The sequence is:
[sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUeCH.png)

[datamapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdiRH.png)

I want to change the node 'name' to 'name'
But if I don't use datamapper, I can print the message in my bak-end service like this:

```
--MIMEBoundary_dc7c91d3bcc67c948c17ffe48106a3f0875e3927d636256b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

dfsdf
--MIMEBoundary_dc7c91d3bcc67c948c17ffe48106a3f0875e3927d636256b--
```

After using data mapper, the message print in my bak-end service like this:

`<mediate><name2>dfsdf</name2></mediate>`

It is obviously out of my suppose, I think I should did something wrong, can any one who can tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try by changing the output schema to contain only `<name2>:[STRING]` without any parent objects (by removing `soapEnv` Envelope and Body fields)

Comment: the schema is very simple:

Comment: I want to show the schema.  I am sorry that I don't know how to add a line break in my comment, I tried to add two spaces but it didn't work......

Comment: the in schema is this: 
`<mediate>`       
`<name>123123</name>`      
`</mediate>`  
  
the out shcema is this:
`<mediate>`
     `<name2>123123</name2>`
`</mediate>`

and in debug I can see the message:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>`
`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">`
    `<soapenv:Body>`
        <xformValues>
           ` <name>123</name>`
      `  </xformValues>`
   ` </soapenv:Body>`
`</soapenv:Envelope>`

Comment: I'm so sorry that my comment is so awful so that it is hard to understand.I just want to change the name of the payload and any other things will not be changed. How could I do, please help me!

Comment: Did you try removing the `{}mediate` entry from the `output` in the datamapper?

Comment: Thank you very much! It' true removing the header fields. I found after the data mapper mediator the payload's content-Type was    
convert to appliaction/xml, so I put a property mediator and set the messageType as application/x-www-urlencoded, and it works!